# Замыкание в JS. Объясните 2 момента

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Здравствуйте!
Разбираю тему замыкания в JS и не могу понять двух моментов в коде с MDN по теме. Объясните пожалуйста (вопросы после кода).

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName; // (1 Вопрос)
};

var myFunc = makeFunc(); // (2 Вопрос)
myFunc();
```

1. Функция возвращается без скобок. Что именно будет возвращено?
2. Зачем функцию makeFunc() сохранять в переменную myFunc, ведь можно вызвать makeFunk() напрямую? Для того чтобы "обернуть" замыкание (displayName + ее окружение)?

Comment: Функция makeFunc(), возвращает другую, только что соданную, функцию, а не ее результат. Из за этого и 1. Ее возвращают без скобок, потому что это это сама функция и она в этот момент не выполняется. 2. Сохраняют в переменную, что бы потом ее вызвать. Конечно если бы ее нужно было вызвать строго один раз можно было бы не делать переменную а вызвать сразу `makeFunc()()`

Comment: @Mike, мог бы сразу ответ писать :)

Comment: То есть, в переменной myFunc будет лежать тело функции displayName?

Comment: @Grundy Мне почему то кажется, что таких вопросов и ответов должно уже быть пару десятков, только искать лень

Comment: @Mike, да вот, иногда проще написать заново, чем дубликат искать

Comment: @anzorovich, там будет лежать **сама функция** displayName

Comment: @anzorovich Можете считать, что тело. Это уже конкретный движок JS решит, что ему хранить. Нормальный движок в целях оптимизации сохранит в переменной указатель на как минимум, разобранную в синтаксическое дерево, готовое для выполнения, функцию. А может даже и на предкомпиленную в некий байт-код, который потом будет быстро выполнятся. (В принципе в плоть до скомпиленного в машинный код, готовый к выполнению на процессоре)

Comment: @Mike спасибо за подробное разъяснение. Можно еще кое что уточнить? В случае с нашим примером, присвоение переменной myFunc функции возвращаемой другой функцией - это только наглядный _учебный_ пример замыкания или в реальной разработке так и используется замыкание?

Comment: @anzorovich Да, так и используется. В реальном коде, особенно асинхронном, возврат и передача куда либо функций, как параметров очень распространенное явление

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Функция возвращается без скобок. Что именно будет возвращено?

Как ни странно, будет возвращена именно эта функция.

> 2. Зачем функцию makeFunc() сохранять в переменную myFunc, ведь можно вызвать makeFunk() напрямую? Для того чтобы "обернуть" замыкание (displayName + ее окружение)?

из пункта выше следует, что `makeFunc()` возвращает новую функцию, которая и сохраняется в переменную, для последующего вызова.

Действительно, можно не сохранять результат и вызвать его сразу

```
makeFunc()();
```

Но для наглядности результат первого вызова был вынесен отдельно.